# Re-posting an unanswered question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I recently had a question that needed answering. I did come across a similar question, but it did not have any answers. I ended up posting my own question. Is there a way to re-post an unanswered question? By linking the previous question to this re-post, the original poster may also get their question answered (assuming the re-post is answered, possibly because its a new/"hot" question that caught the attention of an active member with an answer).

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ways to boost an unanswered question. Adding a bounty is a great way. If your question is different enough, a new question is warranted.

Comment: Other than my offering a bounty on another person's question, is there a way by which the person that posed the original question also get notified of an answer to my question?

Comment: Would making a comment work?

Comment: Commenting on the original unanswered question with a link to the new one with an answer? Sure! I was just wondering if there was something, well, "sleeker" than that - a feature like tagging the other post or some such. Am I terminally bitten by the social media bug?

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to benefit the the person asking the original question, and helping to get good answers to it, is to edit it.

See [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/editing)

By editing the original question, if the edit is approved, you make the question more detailed, clearer, or in some manner better than it was. In its improved condition it may interest others enough to invest the time in creating answers. You don't get your question flagged as a duplicate, and you help improve the site for others - both with a better question, possible answers, and less "noise" when someone else uses the search function later.

I believe the original poster will be notified of the edit, and will be notified of any new answers, or comments to the question. So you won't have to "link" to anything. And, as an edited question,it will be bumped to the top of the home page as well, where it will have a new chance to attract answers.

Comment: Yes, the original poster will be notified of the edit, as they then have the chance to reject the edit.